# Create unique string for iOS5, iOS6 and iOS7 devices

Tags: ios, objective-c

I support my app since iOS5. I have autoreg login which is based on mac-address. In iOS7 Apple will eliminate mac-addresses. UDIDs are also prohibited by Apple. `identifierForVendor` method is available since iOS6. So the question is How can I get some unique string for device if I want to support iOS5 and later.

Comment: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Comment: You will not be able to get a unique identifiers for devices at all with iOS7. [Since you should never ever identifier devices but user](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/).

Comment: @rckoenes, what can you tell about Pradeep's post, about `CFUUID`?

Comment: Use OpenUDID which is simple alternative for unique identifier

Comment: @Satyamsvv [OpenUDID is deprecated](http://blog.appsfire.com/udid-is-dead-openudid-is-deprecated-long-live-advertisingidentifier/). If you are identifying user by there device you are just doing it wrong from the beginning. Apple has changed the rules and with iOS 7 you will no longer be able to identify a deice at all. All unique identifiers can be reset by the user. You should really rethink the way to identify users.

Answer (score 0):

you can get different string which are most likely UDIDs of device and they are different also

```
CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
CFRelease(uuidRef);

NSString *uniqueId = (__bridge NSString *)uuidStringRef;
```

this uniqueId can be used as in place where you want to use UDIDs

Comment: try this code once may be this will help you. if you still face any problem then let me know

Comment: Just to add to this solution, you should save the create `uniqueId` some where save like the keychain. But keep in mind that it the device is reset this `uniqueId` will also be gone.